# Merging two dictionaries with different index

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to merge this dictionary:

```
b = {data:[{station_id: 7000,
 name: "Ft. York / Capreol Crt."
 },
 {station_id: 7001,
  name: "Lower Jarvis St / The Esplanade"}
 ]}
```

and this one:

```
c = {data:[{station_id: 7000,
 num_bikes_available: 18,
 },
 {station_id: 7001,
  num_bikes_available: 4,
  },
 {station_id: 7002,
  num_bikes_available: 10}      
]}
```

and get one dictionary like this:

```
d = {data:[{station_id: 7000,
     name: "Ft. York / Capreol Crt.",
     num_bikes_available: 18
      },
    {station_id: 7001,
     name: "Lower Jarvis St / The Esplanade",                         
     num_bikes_available: 4},
    {station_id: 7002,
     num_bikes_available: 10} 
    ]}
```

How can I do that? have in mind that in c we have a station_id = 7002 which in b we don't.

Comment: I have tried the code for "Merging two dictionaries in Python?" but it gives this error "z.update(c1[station_id]) KeyError: 7002"

Comment: you should give the code you have tried in your question description

Comment: Are those keys `data`, `station_id`, `name`, `num_bikes_available` supposed to be strings?

Comment: You can only accept one answer.

Comment: @kia Pick an answer and accept it once and for all. It isn't fair to users to keep switching :)

Comment: Like Highlander, there can be only one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can start by creating a temp dictionary out of `b` for easy lookup.

```
In [812]: temp = { x['station_id'] : x for x in b['data'] }
```

Next, you iterate over `c` and update dictionaries that exist in `b`:

```
In [813]: d = c.copy()

In [814]: for _dict in d['data']:
     ...:     if _dict['station_id'] in temp:
     ...:         _dict.update(temp[_dict['station_id']])
     ...:         

In [815]: d
Out[815]: 
{'data': [{'name': 'Ft. York / Capreol Crt.',
           'num_bikes_available': 18,
           'station_id': 7000},
          {'name': 'Lower Jarvis St / The Esplanade',
           'num_bikes_available': 4,
           'station_id': 7001},
          {'num_bikes_available': 10, 
           'station_id': 7002}]}
```

Comment: @kia if an answer helped, you can always mark it accepted by clicking on the grey tick next to my answer. It helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps!

```
dct = {'a':'b','b':'c'}
dct1 = {'a':'b','d':'c'}
ndict = dict(dct.items() + dct1.items())
print ndict
```

console output:

```
{'a': 'b', 'b': 'c', 'd': 'c'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = {}
for station_dict in b['data']:
    station_id = station_dict.pop('station_id')
    res.setdefault(station_id, {}).update(station_dict)
for station_dict in c['data']:
    station_id = station_dict.pop('station_id')
    res.setdefault(station_id, {}).update(station_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can unpack each "data" list of dicts into a dict of dicts to make it easier to merge the contents of the inner dicts, and we can then create a new list of dicts in the original format from the merged data. During the merging, we use `.setdefault` to create an empty dict if `c` has a dict that's not present in `b`. The new list is ordered by `station_id`.

```
from pprint import pprint

b = {'data': [{'name': 'Ft. York / Capreol Crt.', 'station_id': 7000},
          {'name': 'Lower Jarvis St / The Esplanade', 'station_id': 7001}]}

c = {'data': [{'num_bikes_available': 18, 'station_id': 7000},
          {'num_bikes_available': 4, 'station_id': 7001},
          {'num_bikes_available': 10, 'station_id': 7002}]}

def unpack(old):
    return {d["station_id"]: d.copy() for d in old['data']}

temp = unpack(b)
for k, v in unpack(c).items():
    temp.setdefault(k, {}).update(v)

# repack
d = {"data": [temp[k] for k in sorted(temp.keys())]}
pprint(d)
```

**output**

```
{'data': [{'name': 'Ft. York / Capreol Crt.',
           'num_bikes_available': 18,
           'station_id': 7000},
          {'name': 'Lower Jarvis St / The Esplanade',
           'num_bikes_available': 4,
           'station_id': 7001},
          {'num_bikes_available': 10, 'station_id': 7002}]}
```

This code can easily be modified to handle more than 2 input objects. Note that the original objects are not altered by the merging process.